# Is it possible to style "external" HTML links differently to "relative" links using CSS alone?

Tags: html, css

Often sites will style links that keep the user in a site differently to those that leave the site. For example:

[image]

In the above the "web address" link directs the user to the Wikipedia page on Web Addresses, while the "stackoverflow.com" link directs the user to the site we know and love.

However, the wikipedia stylesheets include a `.external` class to add the external link icon.

I've dabbled with some of the CSS attribute selectors `a[href='??']` but can't quite get it right, even when using just relative internal links.

**If we assumed that all internal links were relative, can styling internal and external links be done with pure CSS alone?**

Additionally, if we know the address of the current site, can it still be done?

Comment: @guido It's worth noting that Laravel apps and some others always use full URLs, even for internal links.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to *showdev*'s answer, I believe the following is the most accurate selector that works on today's browsers:

```
a[href*='//']{
    /* ... */
}
```

This takes care of different protocols (think `http://` vs `https://`).

Note that, for this to work, you must use relative URLs for all of your *local* links. So `http://example.com/stuff` will be treated as external even if your website is in the *example.com* domain.

Comment: Yeah, that handles both `http` and `https` (and other protocols). Nice idea.

Comment: href^=http will handle both http and https (but not other protocols)

Comment: @guido: What about the protocol-relative links meant to handle `https` automatically (ie. `//google.com`)?

Comment: @JCOC611 that's right, yet very rarely used for `a href` links; more often for loaded resources.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will also match any URL whose path contains an empty path segment, e.g. `/this/is/a/valid//path`, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax).

Answer (score 10):

You can use [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to apply styles conditionally based on the value of the `href`:

```css
/* Links that start with "http" */
a[href^=http] { background-color:red; }

/* Links that don't start with "http" */
a:not([href^=http]) { background-color:lightgreen; }

/* Links that contain a specific domain name */
a[href*=example\.com] { background-color:lightblue; }
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com/">external</a>
<a href="example.html">internal</a>
<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

### Edit:

As mentioned in the answer by JCOC611, it may be more flexible to leave out the "http" part because other schemes (ftp, git, etc.) will not be matched.

Below, I'm testing for the existence of `//` rather than `http`. This will match other schemes and also network-path references. (Of course, it will also erroneously match local links with incorrectly doubled slashes.)

```css
/* Links that contain "//" */
a[href*='//'] { background-color:red; }
```

```html
<a href="//example.com">//example.com</a>
<a href="ftp://example.com">ftp://example.com</a>
<a href="example//fun.html">example//fun.html OOPS!</a>
<a href="example/fun.html">example/fun.html YAY!</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Not yet, no; though, under CSS Selectors Level 4, there's the (potentially incoming) `:local-link` pseudo-class, for example:

```
a:local-link {
    color: red;
}
```

For example, assuming this is on a page hosted on `http://example.com`:

```
<a href="/another/page">Another page</a>
<a href="http://example.com/yet/another/page">Yet another page</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

The above CSS would (or at least *should*, from my reading) style all the links except the one to Google with the colour red.

Though this is yet to be implemented in any browser I've tried, as yet.

Having said that, for `<a>` elements with an absolute URL, the attribute-starts-with selector can help (albeit it works on the `href` attribute, not the JavaScript `href` property); so

```
a[href^=http://example.com] {
    color: green;
}
```

would work only on the element with the text of 'Yet another page'; since the previous element has a root-relative URL which, despite being 'local', does *not* have an `href` attribute starting with `'http://example.com'`.

References:

- [`:local-link`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#local-pseudo).

Comment: As local links on example.com, wouldn't `a:local-link` style the _first two_ links red and **not** style the link to google?

Comment: I...uh, *may* have forgotten what sentence I was typing halfway through, at one point... >.< (thanks! Edited, and corrected!) :)

Answer (score 1):

use the `a[href='??']` rule for your internal links, and use one without it for your external links:

```
a {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
a[href*='http://www.my-website.com'] {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

make sure to put it in that order. Using `[href*=""]` with the added `*` will make sure to grab any href that contains the string given.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ur3rcymc/1/

Comment: Using `a[href*='my-website.com']` is probably sufficient to target internal (absolute) links specifically, as sometimes the `www` is stripped off the URL and/or the server connection might be secure (`https://` instead of `http://`)