# What is the real difference between internal and external links (href)?

Tags: html, url, browser

There are two ways the links can be represented in HTML: internal links refer to objects in the current directory and external to another website ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667617/what-are-internal-and-external-links-on-html-pages)).

But how **another website** is defined? How does my browser actually understand which link is internal? For example,

`<a href="/google.com"> this link will lead you to ./google.com file</a>`

but

`<a href="//google.com"> this link will lead you to the Google website</a>`

So what are the general rules of distinguishing them?

Comment: What do you mean by distinguishing them? External links start with `//` and internals start with `/`

Comment: It parses the `href` as a URL. If the origin is different from the document's, it's external. See [Is it possible to style “external” HTML links differently to “relative” links using CSS alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26898931/215552) for a CSS solution.